# My dropdown menu only works when clicking on home page

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

```
<!-- <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js" async></script> -->
<!-- <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js" async></script> -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" async></script>
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/0d83f3667e.js" async></script>
<script src="<?php echo $assets ?>js/timepicki.min.js" async></script>
<script class="jsbin" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js" async></script>
<script class="jsbin" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.0/jquery-ui.min.js" async></script>
<!-- <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js" async></script> -->    
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" style="border-radius: 0px;">
            <div class="container-fluid" style="background-color: #000; ">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                    </button>
                    <a class="" href="<?php echo base_url();  ?>" style="padding: 20px; ">
                        <img src="<?php echo $assets ?>images/logo.jpg" style="width: 70%; margin-top: 5%; float: left;">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li class="active"><a href="<?php echo base_url();  ?>home" style="background-color: transparent;">Home</a></li>


                        <?php 
                        if($this->session->userdata('user_role') == "vender" or $this->session->userdata('user_role') == "user")
                        {
                            ?>
                            <li><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>booking/user_booking_list">Booking</a></li>
                            <?php
                        }
                        ?>
                        <?php 
                        if($this->session->userdata('user_role') == "vender")
                        {
                            ?>
                            <li class="dropdown">
                                <a class="dropdown-toggle nav-menu" data-toggle="dropdown" style="color:#9d9d9d !important" href="#">My Cars<span class="caret"></span></a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu drop-down-list">
                                    <li><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>venders/add_cars/" class="drop-down-list-item font">Add Car</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>venders/all_cars/?status=approved" class="drop-down-list-item font">View cars</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>venders/all_cars?status=pending" class="font">Pending Approvals</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <?php
                        }
                        ?>
                        <li class="active" style="display:none;"><a href="<?php echo base_url();  ?>about/" style="background-color: transparent;">About</a></li>
                        <li class="active"><a href="<?php echo base_url();  ?>contact/" style="background-color: transparent;">Feedback</a></li>    
                        <li class="active"><a href="<?php echo base_url();  ?>terms/" style="background-color: transparent;">Terms Of Use</a></li>  
                        <li class="active"><a href="<?php echo base_url();  ?>privacy/" style="background-color: transparent;">Privacy Policy</a></li>  
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <?php 
                        if(!$this->session->userdata('user_role'))
                        {
                            ?>
                            <li><a href="<?php echo base_url();  ?>signup"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
                            <li><a href="<?php echo base_url();  ?>login"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
                            <?php
                        }else{

                            ?>
                            <li><a href="<?php echo base_url();  ?>home">Welcome <?php echo ucfirst($this->session->userdata('username')); ?></a></li>
                            <?php 

                        }
                        ?>   
                        <?php 
                        if($this->session->userdata('user_role') == "vender" || $this->session->userdata('user_role') == "user")
                        {
                            ?>
                            <li class="dropdown">
                                <a class="dropdown-toggle nav-menu" data-toggle="dropdown" style="color:#9d9d9d !important" href="#">My Account<span class="caret"></span></a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu drop-down-list">
                                    <li style="display:none;"><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>users/profile/" class="drop-down-list-item font">Profile</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>logout/" class="font">Logout</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <?php
                        }
                        ?>                
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
```

My dropdown menu only works when clicking on the home page. Other pages seem to work fine, only the drop-down "My Cars" does not respond to user interactions on other pages. Besides, it doesn't work at all on mobile. While clicking on the drop-down menu on mobile phone, nothing happens. What could be the problem? here is my site: http://www.yiyalo.com.
Link to my source code : https://github.com/stephenleong/MyProject

Comment: Do you have any errors in the browser's console? Also, how is it not working? Is it not opening? Can you given me a URL where I can test this without registering?

Comment: use my testing account
id:qy_leong13@hotmail.com 
pass:123456

Answer (score 0):

Change your `li` wrapping the code to a `div`

Example:

Before:

```
<li class="dropdown">
<a class="dropdown-toggle nav-menu" data-toggle="dropdown" style="color:#9d9d9d !important" href="#">My Cars<span class="caret"></span></a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu drop-down-list">
     <li><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>venders/add_cars/" class="drop-down-list-item font">Add Car</a></li>
     <li><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>venders/all_cars/?status=approved" class="drop-down-list-item font">View cars</a></li>
     <li><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>venders/all_cars?status=pending" class="font">Pending Approvals</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
```

After:

```
<div class="dropdown"> <!-- Here -->
<a class="dropdown-toggle nav-menu" data-toggle="dropdown" style="color:#9d9d9d !important" href="#">My Cars<span class="caret"></span></a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu drop-down-list">
     <li><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>venders/add_cars/" class="drop-down-list-item font">Add Car</a></li>
     <li><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>venders/all_cars/?status=approved" class="drop-down-list-item font">View cars</a></li>
     <li><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>venders/all_cars?status=pending" class="font">Pending Approvals</a></li>
</ul>
</div> <!-- And here -->
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of errors you have, fixing them should be your first priority. If they are fixed and the problem still persists, then you will need to solve the problem, like this:

```
$(".dropdown-toggle:first").click(function(e) {
    var brothers = $(this).siblings("ul");
    brothers[(brothers.css("display") !== "block") ? "show" : "hide"]();
}).blur(function(e) {
    var brothers = $(this).siblings("ul");
    brothers.hide();
});
```

Where `click` will handle your `click` event, `blur` your `blur` event, notice how I have played with the `hide` and `show` `function` names.